# How to replace json key value using php regular expression?

Tags: php, json, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I have a invalid json string like this :

```
{
   "cat":{
      "id":"1234567",
      "source_id":null,
      "title_en":"first season",
      "description_en":"This is spring category "
   },
   "videos":[
      {
         "id":"312412343",
         "url":"\/2015-07-17\/1abcd.mp4",
         "img":"image\/44\/\/2015-07-17\/1abcd.jpg",
         "description1":"some text for" description here",
         "description2":"some text for" description here2",
         "title":"first title here"

      },
      {
         "id":"2342343",
         "url":"\/2015-07-16\/2dcdeg.mp4",
         "img":"images\/44\/\/2015-07-16\/2dcdeg.jpg",
         "description1":"some other text here" for description ",
         "description2":"some other text here" for description2 ",
         "title":"second title here"

      }
   ]
}
```

I want to change the value of description1 and description2 to word empty using regular expression. Could any one help me how to achieve this using regular expression ?Thanks.

```
     "description1":"empty",
     "description2":"empty",
```

Comment: Make it simple. Decode your json, change the array value and then encode it again.

Comment: Thanks for reply.My JSON is not valid all the time  (some time it has double quote in description1 and description2).I don't you if your suggested method will work for invalid JSON so  I would prefer a regex .

Comment: Then you are solving the wrong problem. If you expect json you should get valid json, otherwise you do something wrong. If you need to solve it with a regex it won't make the problem better.

Comment: The api that i use gives me invalid json so i can't do anything unless i fix the json myself by somehow make descrption2 and description 1 empty! But don't know how!

Comment: Then the API is crap. But make sure to include that information inside your question that you sometimes have invliad json. Also take a look at https://regex101.com to play around and construct a regex :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$result = json_decode($json, true);
array_walk($result['videos'], function (&$item) {$item['description1'] = 'empty'; $item['description2'] = 'empty';});
$json = json_encode($result);
print_r($json);
```

Solution with regex:

```
print_r(preg_replace('/\"description(1|2)\"\:\".*?\"\,/s', '"description$1":"empty",',$json));
```

Comment: I tried your solution and i got {"videos":null} !My json got double quote inside description 2 and description1!

Comment: Many thanks your updated solution worked but if the description is across multiple lines(mix of unicode and non unicode)then it fails! Is there any way to make your preg_replace work if description2 and descripitoin1 values are long(not on online line) ?

Comment: The answer is updated @user1788736

Comment: May i know why you used \:.*?\,/s instead of \:.*?\"\,/s ? for my case the second method worked!(replaced entire description values with word empty which i wanted! :-)Thanks alot.

Comment: @user1788736 It's more correct to use  *?\"\, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $json = '{
   "cat":{
      "id":"1234567",
      "source_id":null,
      "title_en":"first season",
      "description_en":"This is spring category "
   },
   "videos":[
      {
         "id":"312412343",
         "url":"\/2015-07-17\/1abcd.mp4",
         "img":"image\/44\/\/2015-07-17\/1abcd.jpg",
         "description1":"some text for description here",
         "description2":"some text for description here2",
         "title":"first title here"

      },
      {
         "id":"2342343",
         "url":"\/2015-07-16\/2dcdeg.mp4",
         "img":"images\/44\/\/2015-07-16\/2dcdeg.jpg",
         "description1":"some other text here" for description ",
         "description2":"some other text here" for description2 ",
         "title":"second title here"

      }
   ]
}';

$json = preg_replace('/(description\d+":)"(.*)"/', '$1"empty"', $json);
echo '<pre>' . $json . '</code>';
$json = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($json);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/NW7pq)

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to regular expression.
You can use these lines of code:

```
$str = <<<'json_str'
{
   "cat":{
      "id":"1234567",
      "source_id":null,
      "title_en":"first season",
      "description_en":"This is spring category "
   },
   "videos":[
      {
         "id":"312412343",
         "url":"\/2015-07-17\/1abcd.mp4",
         "img":"image\/44\/\/2015-07-17\/1abcd.jpg",
         "description1":"some text for description here",
         "description2":"some text for description here2",
         "title":"first title here"

      },
      {
         "id":"2342343",
         "url":"\/2015-07-16\/2dcdeg.mp4",
         "img":"images\/44\/\/2015-07-16\/2dcdeg.jpg",
         "description1":"some other text here for description ",
         "description2":"some other text here for description2 ",
         "title":"second title here"

      }
   ]
}
json_str;
$arr = json_decode($str);
$arr['videos']['empty'] = $arr['videos']['description1'] ;
unset($arr['videos']['description1']);
$converted_to_json = json_encode($arr);
```

in these lines I converted the json string to array using `json_decode()` function. Then I replaced description1 keys in array with empty and converted it again to json string using `json_encode()` function.

I hope my answer be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does your method work if i got invalid json for example if i have double quote inside descrition1 and description2 ?